# C++: T-distribution value

Tags: c++, statistics, distribution

I want to get the value of `t-distribution` in C++, in a way similar to what could be done in python, like:

```python
t = stats.t.isf(q=(alpha / n) / 2, df=n - 2)
```

I have seen this documentation:

[student_t_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/student_t_distribution/)

and tried to manipulate the example written there, however, I still need a some help.
What I want to do eventually is to get `t-distribution` value in a way like:

```c
t = t_distFunction(alpha, degree_of_freedom);
cout << "t= " << t;
>> t= 2.88
```

Is that possible using the class I mentioned above? and if not, how can I get the t_dist value?

Comment: No. C++ standard for distributions does not provide either PDF or CDF or survival functions, or PPF. You'd better write them yourself or use BOOST or GSL

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux sorry for my limited knowledge, but I have no idea about any of the names you mentioned. Could you please help with some references?

Comment: BOOST is collection of high quality C++ libraries, but not part of C++ standard. Take a look at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/dist.html for statistical functions. GNU Scientific Library is another set of high quality C libiraries, not part of the C or C++ standard, take a look https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: Basically, I'm saying to get what you want you have to look beyond C++ standard. I proposed two high quality libraries which might be of help, but there are other libraries as well.